# Using CSS selectors first of type and not first child together

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to do some styling using purely CSS selectors, my markup looks like this:

```html
<div class="StyledRow">
   <div class="Row">Input 1</div>
   <div class="Row">Input 2</div>
</div>

<div class="StyledRow">
   <div class="Row">Input 1</div>
   <div class="Row">Input 2</div>
</div>

<div class="StyledRow">
   <div class="Row">Input 1</div>
   <div class="Row">Input 2</div>
</div>
```

The rendered elements are inputs side by side (2) and then stacked on top of one another (so the user can add as many data sets as they wish)

The above is a simplified version but because of additional elements, I need to be a bit more specific with my styles. For example, the current style of `StyledRow` looks like this:

```js
const StyledRow = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  *:not(:first-child) > * {
    margin-left: 0.2rem;
  }
`;
```

I am trying to target the second `Row` in the first `StyledRow` so that the styles can be different from the rest which use a margin-left: 0.2rem. I had tried to use first-of-type and not-first-child together but with no joy.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```css
*:not(:first-child) > * {
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
}
```

it will apply that to everything. So if you use

```css
.StyledRow:not(:first-child) > * {
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
}
```

the styling will be applied on every iteration of StyledRow apart from the first one.

If you use:

```css
.StyledRow:nth-child(2) > * {
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
}
```

then that will specifically target the second iteration of StyledRow.